# Ditto command and wildcard on Catalina?

Tags: terminal, command-line, zsh

I've learnt a bit about ditto and tried this:

```
mkdir testingdir

ditto myfile.css testingdir
```

which seemed to work.

How could I ditto one file , e.g. myfile.css to several folders within testingdir, e.g. dir1, dir2, dir3 using zsh on Catalina?

Learning about ditto and tried Google'ing but am not sure.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `for` loop for this (works in both `zsh` and `bash`):

```
for target in "dir1" "dir2" "dir3"; do
    ditto -- "myfile.css" "testingdir/$target"
done
```

If the target directories are actually called `dir1` etc you can use wildcard expansion

```
for target in dir[1-3]; do
    ditto -- "myfile.css" "testingdir/$target"
done
```

Comment: Both example also work in `ksh` and `dash` .